# Cyber source implementing device fingerprint

Tags: javascript, php, payment, payment-processing, cybersource

how can I implement a device fingerprint on the web site? after adding the fingerprinting code to my website with mandatory fields (org ID, merchant ID, session ID) with the supported tags  and  like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://h.online-metrix.net/fp/ tags.js?org_id=<org ID>&session_id=<merchant ID><session ID>"></ script>

<noscript>
    <iframe style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 0; position: absolute; top: -5000px;" src="https://h.online-metrix.net/fp/tags?org_ id=<org ID>&session_id=<merchant ID><session ID>"></iframe>
</noscript>
```

I put the first script inside head tag a second noScript tag inside the body tag

The first `script` returns status code 204 i think that is fine but the second (`<noscript>`) returs 400 bad request. and if this is not work cyber coruce can't find the fingrprint from the server (https://h.online-metrix.net.....) so how can i fix this issue this is my first time working on payment integration with cyber cource.

Thanks